# Configuring a script with multiple options

Tags: bash, scripts

I am writing a script for my personal use and learning.
I would like to have few options to change/configure at the top of my script which I can change every time I execute the script.
Below is just a random example of what I want to achieve.
I would like to configure the script so that: If I define `Backup="timeshift"` then the relevant commands should be executed for e.g.

```
Command 1 #install timeshift
Command 2 #configure timeshit
Command 3 #make a backup with timeshift
```

But if I define `Backup="snapper"` then it should install the relevant commands NOT the timeshift ones.

```
Command 4 #install snapper
Command 5 #configure snapper
Command 6 #make a backup with snapper
```

I also need the script at certain parts to either execute some commands or do nothing. For e.g. `network_backup="true"` then:

```
Command 7 # upload to the cloud storage
```

But if I defined `network_backup="false"` at the top of the script then nothing should be executed.

I am a beginner in writing scripts.
What is the easiest way to achieve what I explained.
I am happy if someone can explain another/better way of achieving the above.

Comment: you will need to learn `if` statements in bash. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

You know the problem you want to solve. That's the first step. And you also know what success looks like to you; that's the second. What's missing is how to think about the route between what you want and what you've got.

Since you're learning, I'll suggest what I think might be the optimal way to do it, and it's up to you to write the code.

For each backup program you want to be able to run, write a [bash function](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html) that runs the commands to:

1. Determine if the program is installed;
2. Install it if it isn't;
3. Determine if the program is configured as you want it to be;
4. Configure it if it isn't; and
5. Return an [exit code](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html) letting you how things went.

Then you might show the user a list of programs (a menu) and have them choose one. This will call the appropriate function.

After that, either the desired program installed and configured or it's not, and you know which one is the case. If it failed, you want to quit so you can investigate; if it succeeded, you'll run the program. Please grab the exit code from this as well.

As far as the rest, the "execute commands or do nothing", it's simple enough to set up one or more "yes/no" prompts, taking the backup program's exit code into consideration.

(Now, if it were I, I'd write a separate script for each program. But I prefer simplicity and I don't mind maintaining two or three simple scripts instead of one more complicated one.)

Comment: To save you a little searching, here's how I like to test if a program is installed: 

`command -v timeshift > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo "Installed" || echo "Not Installed"`